# Can you toggle the visibility of the status bar in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I know you can turn the status bar on and off with

```
set -g status off
```

But I would like to bind a key to *toggle* the visibility of this status bar.  Is there some way to toggle this setting?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Boolean options can be toggled when no value is given:

```
set -g status
```

Comment: Remove `-g` to toggle locally.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to bind a key, add this to you `.tmuxrc`:

```
bind-key -n C-F3 set-option -g status #Ctrl+F3 Combo
```